# Only inserting specific rows from csv file into Sqlite3 database using python

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I am trying to import csv files into a sqlite3 database which I'm writing using python. I'm fairly new to importing data this way and to sqlite3 in general.

The data files I've got tend to have an irregular format at the beginning, but the rows I want will always begin with a date field (dd/mm/yy) and time field (hh:mm:ss). 
Example file is below:

```
Hello I am a file, , , ,
I am a type of csv file, , , ,
Date, Time, ID number, Message
12/12/2012, 13:12:13, 1, Hello World
13/12/2012, 13:12:13, 2, Goodbye
```

So I want to just import the 4th and 5th rows (and all subsequent rows with a date), but skip the first 3 which describe the file and column headers.

So far I've got the code which reads in the data and then puts it into a table along with a unique identifier (logID), but at the moment I'm just reading from line 4 onwards - I'd like a more general solution for the case when a file doesn't have the 3 leading rows of blurb.

```
#code above here opens the database and creates a cursor
with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
    for row in reader:
        if reader.line_num >= 4:
            values = logID + str(row[0]) + str(row[1]) + str(row[2]) + str(row[3])
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(" +values+ ");")
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting the first item in `row` into a Python [datetime.datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object. If it works, process the line, if not, [continue](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) through the loop:

```
import datetime as DT
with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
    for row in reader:
        try:
            date = DT.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y')
        except ValueError:
            continue 
    args = [logID] + row  
    sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ({})".format(', '.join(['?']*len(args)))
    cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

---

The above will work for small to moderate-sized CSV. If you have a huge CSV file, calling `cursor.execute` once per line can be slow. To improve the performance, read a chunk of (say, 1000) lines at a time, and accumulate the values to be inserted into a list of lists, `manyargs`. Then call

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", manyargs)
```

once per chunk.

---

By the way, constructing SQL commands with string formatting such as:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(" +values+ ");")
```

can be a security risk. A maliciously constructed CSV file could take advantage of this line to run arbitrary SQL comands (see [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)). To protect against this, use parametrized SQL:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", args)
```

The `?` is a placemarker -- one placemarker for each field value. The `args` is a sequence (such as a tuple or list) containing the values you wish to insert. Note that the `args` is passed as a second argument to `cursor.execute`. You do not have to convert the values in `args` to strings (though in this case, they are strings since `csv.reader` yields lists of strings). The sqlite3 module will handle the quoting of the arguments for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'd spotted the datetime conversion in other solutions but wasn't sure how to implement it. I'm expecting this software to be passed data for different tables with differing numbers of columns. Can I still use parameterized SQL or do you have to be able to define the number of "?" in the statement?

Comment: I've modified the code above to show how you can handle an arbitrary number of columns.